# setting EmailSettingNames.Smtp.EnableSsl results in a "String was not recognized as a valid Boolean" error

Tags: asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I've setup aspnet boilerplate to send emails. I've set default values using the following:

```
    public class AppSettingProvider : SettingProvider
{
    public override IEnumerable<SettingDefinition> GetSettingDefinitions(SettingDefinitionProviderContext context)
    {
        return new[]
        {
            new SettingDefinition(EmailSettingNames.DefaultFromAddress, "", scopes: SettingScopes.Application | SettingScopes.Tenant | SettingScopes.User, isVisibleToClients: true, isInherited: true),
            new SettingDefinition(EmailSettingNames.DefaultFromDisplayName, "", scopes: SettingScopes.Application | SettingScopes.Tenant | SettingScopes.User, isVisibleToClients: true, isInherited: true),
            new SettingDefinition(EmailSettingNames.Smtp.Host, "127.0.0.1", scopes: SettingScopes.Application | SettingScopes.Tenant | SettingScopes.User, isVisibleToClients: true, isInherited: true),
            new SettingDefinition(EmailSettingNames.Smtp.Port, "25", scopes: SettingScopes.Application | SettingScopes.Tenant | SettingScopes.User, isVisibleToClients: true, isInherited: true),
            new SettingDefinition(EmailSettingNames.Smtp.UserName, XXXXX, scopes: SettingScopes.Application | SettingScopes.Tenant | SettingScopes.User, isVisibleToClients: true, isInherited: true),
            new SettingDefinition(EmailSettingNames.Smtp.Password, XXXXX, scopes: SettingScopes.Application | SettingScopes.Tenant | SettingScopes.User, isVisibleToClients: true, isInherited: true),
            new SettingDefinition(EmailSettingNames.Smtp.Domain, string.Empty, scopes: SettingScopes.Application | SettingScopes.Tenant | SettingScopes.User, isVisibleToClients: true, isInherited: true),
            new SettingDefinition(EmailSettingNames.Smtp.EnableSsl, "true", scopes: SettingScopes.Application | SettingScopes.Tenant | SettingScopes.User, isVisibleToClients: true, isInherited: true),
            new SettingDefinition(EmailSettingNames.Smtp.UseDefaultCredentials, string.Empty, scopes: SettingScopes.Application | SettingScopes.Tenant | SettingScopes.User, isVisibleToClients: true, isInherited: true)
        };
    }
}
```

But when I send the email it generates an "String was not recognized as a valid Boolean" exception, how else do I define the EmailSettingNames.Smtp.EnableSsl property so that it applies correctly?

Comment: Are you able to share the stacktrace of the exception ?

Comment: The exception occurs when calling _emailSender.Send, stack trace in the following link:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/6yion3er0fd5xkp/stacktrace.txt?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the correct one:

```
public class AppSettingProvider : SettingProvider
{
    public override IEnumerable<SettingDefinition> GetSettingDefinitions(SettingDefinitionProviderContext context)
    {
        return new[]
        {
            new SettingDefinition(EmailSettingNames.DefaultFromAddress, "", scopes: SettingScopes.Application | SettingScopes.Tenant | SettingScopes.User, isVisibleToClients: true, isInherited: true),
            new SettingDefinition(EmailSettingNames.DefaultFromDisplayName, "", scopes: SettingScopes.Application | SettingScopes.Tenant | SettingScopes.User, isVisibleToClients: true, isInherited: true),
            new SettingDefinition(EmailSettingNames.Smtp.Host, "127.0.0.1", scopes: SettingScopes.Application | SettingScopes.Tenant | SettingScopes.User, isVisibleToClients: true, isInherited: true),
            new SettingDefinition(EmailSettingNames.Smtp.Port, "25", scopes: SettingScopes.Application | SettingScopes.Tenant | SettingScopes.User, isVisibleToClients: true, isInherited: true),
            new SettingDefinition(EmailSettingNames.Smtp.UserName, XXXXX, scopes: SettingScopes.Application | SettingScopes.Tenant | SettingScopes.User, isVisibleToClients: true, isInherited: true),
            new SettingDefinition(EmailSettingNames.Smtp.Password, XXXXX, scopes: SettingScopes.Application | SettingScopes.Tenant | SettingScopes.User, isVisibleToClients: true, isInherited: true),
            new SettingDefinition(EmailSettingNames.Smtp.Domain, string.Empty, scopes: SettingScopes.Application | SettingScopes.Tenant | SettingScopes.User, isVisibleToClients: true, isInherited: true),
            new SettingDefinition(EmailSettingNames.Smtp.EnableSsl, "true", scopes: SettingScopes.Application | SettingScopes.Tenant | SettingScopes.User, isVisibleToClients: true, isInherited: true),
            new SettingDefinition(EmailSettingNames.Smtp.UseDefaultCredentials, "false", scopes: SettingScopes.Application | SettingScopes.Tenant | SettingScopes.User, isVisibleToClients: true, isInherited: true)
        };
    }
}
```

---

Corrected: `UseDefaultCredentials` cannot be empty string.